# Script running fine on live server but not on wamp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wampserver

I recently bought a script from code canyon that seems to be working fine on live server, but not on WAMP (Apache Version :2.2.22 ), the requirement of the script is that mod-rewrite should be on and it seems to be on

[image]

In www folder of wamp my code resides inside folder called `jobs` and this is how i am accessing it `http://localhost/jobs` But each time it redirects me to `http://localhost/jobs/US/` and all i see is WAMP Server Configuration Screen.

On live server this is what `.htaccess` looks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^careers.clickteck.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.careers.clickteck.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have not worked with `.htaccess` that much so i am not sure what to do to make the script work on localhost, I did try to change `RewriteBase` from `RewriteBase /` to `RewriteBase /jobs` but that did not work either.

I do not see anything inside `apache error log`, however I see this code in `apache access log`

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jul/2014:22:32:41 +0500] "GET /jobs/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jul/2014:22:32:42 +0500] "GET /jobs/US/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5924
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jul/2014:22:32:43 +0500] "GET /jobs/US/index.php?img=pngFolder HTTP/1.1" 200 850
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jul/2014:22:32:43 +0500] "GET /jobs/US/index.php?img=gifLogo HTTP/1.1" 200 4549
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jul/2014:22:32:43 +0500] "GET /jobs/US/index.php?img=pngWrench HTTP/1.1" 200 741
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jul/2014:22:32:43 +0500] "GET /jobs/US/index.php?img=pngPlugin HTTP/1.1" 200 548
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jul/2014:22:32:43 +0500] "GET /jobs/US/index.php?img=pngFolderGo HTTP/1.1" 200 694
```

I will really really appreciate if anyone can tell me what am i doing wrong or how to get it to work on localhost.

**SOLUTION**

I made the following change in `.htaccess` which solved the problem

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
--->   RewriteRule . jobs/index.php [L]   <----

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Since you bought a script from code canyon, have you tried asking code canyon for help? I don't mean to dismiss your question here, but they might know their script better than the SO community, and might have a particular work-around for WAMP vs LAMP.

Comment: @TecBrat yes I contacted the author, been waiting for 4 days now so thought of asking here.

Comment: @Baig don't be afraid of putting your solution in an actual answer; you can even accept it as such

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier thanks, I guess i should do that in case someone in future comes across the same scenario. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by studying wordpress `.htaccess` file on localhost and came to a solution that since the script resides inside a folder called `jobs` I needed to add this in `.htaccess` file also by doing this`RewriteRule . jobs/index.php [L]`.

This is the complete `.htaccess` code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . jobs/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Delete `RewriteBase /`.
Replace `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` instead of `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`